# How can I get the python to only count if I input $1?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def bills():
 counts = 0
 while True:
   bills = int(input("Insert your bills:$"))
   if bills > 1:
    counts += 1
    print("Only accept $1 bill!")
    print(counts)
   elif bills == 0:
    break
```

I only want it keep count if the bills is $1. And total up that count. 
Thanks

Comment: You can test whether the user entered 1 by checking `if bills == 1`. But it's not clear what you want to do in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Tim Pierce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977243/how-can-i-get-the-python-to-only-count-if-i-input-1#comment46206292_28977243) pointed out, you just needed to add the condition `elif bills == 1`:

```
def bills():
    counts = 0
    while True:
        bills = int(input("Insert your bills:$"))

        if bills > 1:                #If input is greater than 1, print error and count
            print("Only accept $1 bill!")
            print(counts) 
        elif bills ==1:              #If input equals 1, increment and then print count
            counts += 1
            print(counts)
        else:                        #If input is less than 1, exit function
            break
bills()
```